# Remove variable ending from text file

Tags: text-processing

How can I use a script to get rid of the last `-xyz.mp4` in a **text** file list.

Right now I have a long `text` list that I need changing from

```
55363642b-b13218-4cb0-8334-546565346-384.mp4
gfdggwg-e1321-4qwe-9ewq-de32155139d8-360.mp4
```

To

```
55363642b-b13218-4cb0-8334-546565346
gfdggwg-e1321-4qwe-9ewq-de32155139d8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ sed 's/-[^-]*\.mp4$//' file
55363642b-b13218-4cb0-8334-546565346
gfdggwg-e1321-4qwe-9ewq-de32155139d8
```

The `sed` expression `s/-[^-]*\.mp4$//` is a substitution that matches a dash followed by any number of non-dashes, a dot and the string `mp4` (at the very end of the line). The matching text is removed.

To make the change in-place, use the `-i` flag of `sed` (but run without first to make sure the result is correct):

```
sed -i 's/-[^-]*\.mp4$//' file
```

---

If these were names of files, I would loop over the actual files instead:

```
for mp4file in *.mp4; do
    printf 'The truncated name is "%s"\n' "${mp4file%-*.mp4}"
done
```

The parameter substitution `${mp4file%-*.mp4}` would expand to the name of the file with the shortest string matching `-*.mp4` removed from the end.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` solution.  Looks for a hyphen, followed by 3 characters, followed by .mp4, followed by end of line ($), and replaces with nothing.

Read "file", write shorter names to file "newfile".

```
sed 's/-...\.mp4$//g' file >newfile
```

or edit "file" in place

```
sed -i 's/-...\.mp4$//g' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F- -vOFS=- 'NF{NF-=1};1' file
```

This will delimit each line with `-` and remove the last field, then print the remaining fields with the dash re-added.